# Php mysql обернуть массив mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat where limit 2");  //пример, записей на много больше
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
         echo '<p>'.$row['msg'].$row['login'].'</p>';
}
```

Записи

```
msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4
```

Как сделать, чтобы вывело в таком порядке? Именно msg3, потом msg4. Пробовал `order by id desc` и `array_reverse`, но не помогло.

Comment: order by id asc?

Comment: выведет msg1,msg2

Comment: Чето не понял у меня такое впечетление что надо просто limit 2 убрать ))

Comment: нужно именно две записи из таблицы

Comment: Всеравно неясно но попрбую методом тыка ))
SELECT * FROM chat order by id asc limit 2,2 так пробовали

Comment: выведет msg3,msg4.  
но если добавлю еще запись msg5.  
то выведет так же msg3,msg4.

Comment: в теории надо чтобы вывело последние 100 записей из таблицы, в порядке от меньшему к большему. то есть последние записи должны быть в конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот теперь уже ясно

Вариант 1

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `chat`");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
$total_rows=$row[0];
//Получили количество срок в таблице

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat order by id asc limit".($total_rows-100).",100");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
         echo '<p>'.$row['msg'].$row['login'].'</p>';
}
```

Вариант 2

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat order by id desc limit 100");  
$array_of_row = array()
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $array_of_row[] = $row; 
}
 $array_of_row = array_reverse($array_of_row);

foreach ($array_of_row as $row) {
         echo '<p>'.$row['msg'].$row['login'].'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'SELECT * FROM  `mytable` ORDER BY  `mytable`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0,10'

Вернет последние 10 записей из таблицы